# Why does ajax call breaks jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

EDIT #2: This is exactly whats going on with me, except its not WP: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5683/loading-dynamic-content-with-ajax-breaking-jquery. How would I do this with my scripts???

EDIT: The real problem is that when I load the page, it works fine, ajax isn't being called. But once it does get called. all the rest of my scripts just stops. How do I rerun the scripts after the ajax call? I verified this from Firebug Console. The below problem is also might be causing it..

Guys I am really begging for someone to help mewith this, I need this fixed :(

Go [here](http://static9.me/clients/witza/)

Look at the 'Current Projects' section—the list of links and the definition box.

Now on the navigation, click on another page, then return back to home. The whole section 'Current Projects' is broken, the list items stop being hidden (hidden by JS), the scrollbar is also broken.

I think it is because ajax loads another div next to original div, and that causes the site to break.

**Example:**

***On page load:***

```
<div id="main-content">
..content...
</div>
```

***After clicking to another page then returning***

```
<div id="main-content" class="home">
<div id="main-content" class="home">
    ..content...
</div>
</div>
```

How would I stop this from happening?

**jQuery:**

Relating to the Current Project Section:

```
$dd = $('.projects dl').find('dd'), $defBox = $('#def-box');

  $defBox.hide();
  $('.projects').hover(function(){
    $defBox.stop(true, true)
      .fadeToggle(1000)
      .html('<p>Hover The links to see a description</p>');
  });

  $dd.hide();
  $('.projects dl dt').hover(function(){
    var $data = $(this).next('dd').html();
    $defBox.html($data);
    });
```

**Ajax**

```
// Ajax Stuff 
  // Check for hash value in URL  
  var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);

  //  Check to ensure that a link with href == hash is on the page  
  if ($('a[href="' + hash + '"]').length) {
    //  Load the page.
    var toLoad = hash + '.php #main-content';
    $('#main-content').load(toLoad);
  }
 $('nav ul li a').click(function(){
    var goingTo = $(this).attr('href');
    goingTo = goingTo.substring(goingTo.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    if (window.location.hash.substring(1) === goingTo) return false;

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #main-content',
    $content = $('#main-content'), $loadimg = $('#load');

    $content.fadeOut('fast',loadContent);  
      $loadimg.remove();  
      $content.append('<span id="load"></span>');  
      $loadimg.fadeIn('slow');  
    window.location.hash = goingTo;

    function loadContent() {  
        $content.load(toLoad,'',showNewContent)  
    }  
    function showNewContent() {  
        $content.fadeIn('fast',hideLoader);  
    }  
    function hideLoader() {  
        $loadimg.fadeOut('fast');  
    }  
    return false;  

  });
```

Now I think that is the problem,i'm not sure, can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose one solution is for you to refine your selector which you pass to jQuery's load function so it inserts #main-content's children instead of itself.

For example you can put a wrapper element in #main-content like
`<div id="main-content"><div id="main-content-wrapper">...` and then change your ajax urls to
`$(this).attr('href')+' #main-content-wrapper'`.

Or I'm not sure but using `$(this).attr('href')+' #main-content > *'` might work too without the need for a wrapper element.

Comment: Seems you haven't changed the ajax content selector:
`var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #main-content'` to `var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #main-content-wrapper'`
and:
`var toLoad = hash + '.php #main-content'` to `var toLoad = hash + '.php #main-content-wrapper'`
and also put the wrapper div in all pages

Comment: You know what maybe it be simpler to load your content into a hidden div and then replace #main-content with loaded content.

Answer (score 1):

you are applying tinyscrollbar plugin on page load. Once you navigate back to home page, you need to reapply the tinyscrollbar plugin again.

when u load the page ( http://static9.me/clients/witza/ ) , u r doing http://gyazo.com/038351a0773b519c3bb36ff6952dacfa.png u need to run this script again when u click home (http://static9.me/clients/witza/#home )

when u load the page without #home, there is no ajax request to get home content right? and the script is in the footer of the page. which works fine. but when u click home the url become...#home and u load the home content with ajax. so u need to apply that plugin again. try clicking the home link in navigation and run that tinyscrollbar script in ur console. u will see what i mean

Answer (score 0):

That does indeed seem to be your problem. You need to either put that content into a parent container that you will use to insert into, or you need to insert a child container of the main-content for home.php

You don't want to put a container into itself, as this will keep happening recursively without  a page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

http://jsbin.com/uhuci5/2/

Write ur code like this, not the other way you are trying to do.